# Where to find resources in Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, html

EDIT:

I able to found where CSS resides in salesforce:

> https://XXXX.visual.force.com/sCSS/34.0/sprites/1438195776000/Theme3/default/gc/extended.css

I inherit someone's code trying to understand where does these images/css resides in salesforce, I have looked at the `resources` but could not find specific to what I'm looking here and also I do not find any `url` in the `vf/apex code` that refers to CSS/Images

> styleClass="picklistArrowRight" value="/s.gif"
>
> styleClass="picklistArrowLeft" value="/s.gif"

```
<apex:image styleClass="picklistArrowRight" value="/s.gif">
   <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!ClickRight}" reRender="BoxPanel" />
       </apex:image>
         <br /> <br />
           <apex:image styleClass="picklistArrowLeft" value="/s.gif">
              <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!ClickLeft}" reRender="BoxPanel" />
</apex:image>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are described in the common.css file also the lookup icon is in ...my.salesforce.com/img/func_icons/util/lookup20.gif

The below css class is defined in the common.css file.

**The lookup icon css class example:**

```
.lookupIcon {
  background-image: url(/img/func_icons/util/lookup20.gif);
  background-position: 0 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-position: top left;
}
```

**Firebug screenshot of the lookup icon:**

[image]

So you just need to add "lookupIcon" css class name in your apex:image tag as shown below:

```
<apex:image styleClass="picklistArrowLeft lookupIcon" value="/s.gif">
```

**An additional screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: yes I could have hack to find out but I really wanted to understand how those resources get used.

Comment: Yes, your "picklistArrowLeft" css class defined in extended.css file and the icon  for it is ...visual.force.com/img/alohaSkin/combobox_arrows_sprite.gif. Just try to use a firebug. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I attached an additional screenshot, take a look. To access the extended.css file just click on it in firebug window.